# Turn affiliate query parameter "r" into UTM tags on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, query-string, affiliate, utm

I have people referring traffic to my website using a URL like this:

```
domain.com?r=1234
```

Each affiliate has a unique "r" code. How can I detect the query parameter "r" on the pageview of my website and translate it into a set of UTM tags that can be detected by Google Analytics, so that I can see which users are doing what on my Google Analytics reports? The mapping would be something like this:

```
If URL contains ?r=1234 -> Send to Google Analytics as ?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=1234
```

The idea is being able to see the traffic coming thanks to these affiliates together with the rest of the traffic coming from other medium/campaigns (using UTM tags) and have the option to filter by medium or campaign on Google Analytics, so I guess the only way is turning the "r" query parameter into UTM tags. However, I'm open to other solutions. Thanks a lot!

Edit: At the moment, I'm able to capture the "r" query parameter using Google Tag Manager. As I'm tracking the pageviews and other goals using Google Tag Manager, the idea would be *attaching* the parameter "r" somewhere within the tag, so that Google Analytics detects it. Or something equivalent.

Comment: Curious as to why you don't just remake the referral links with the UTM tags. That's the point of them: to make it easy to get metadata on your referall links. What do you accomplish (or avoid) trying to find an extra step to add in?

Comment: @user7778287 it's basically to avoid sharing long crazy URLs full of UTM tags. People tend to think of UTM tags as a tool to track them, while a referral parameter is more likely to be perceived as a way to reward the person who referred them. It's also easier to share and understand by affiliates. However, I'm not sure how to make Google Analytics translate the referral parameter (e.g. "r") into UTM tags. I'm open to some other way to handle query parameters to track user behaviour along the funnel together with other campaigns that have been tracked using UTM tags.

Comment: Well its pretty hacky, but without knowing almost anything about Google Analytics the easiest solution I can think of is to make a script on your host(s) such that when a referral link is served the host posts a request with a URL containing the UTM tags you desire.

Comment: Hmmm not sure how I could achieve that, but will give it a thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UTM directly and share a short URL generated i.e. with a online service. Anyway you have to add utm_medium because it is mandatory, and referral is medium not source.

You can also override source / medium / campaign value forcing them in page or via GTM.

i.e. based querystring parameter you can configure GA tag similar to this (where variables values will be what you want):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Indeed, that was definitely an idea I had in mind, but when users click on the shortened link and go to the website, they see the UTM tags. So the shortened version won't stand. And you're totally right, medium would be referral. I was wondering if there's another solution so that on the URL bar the user always sees the "r" parameter, but behind the scenes, we detect it's a UTM tag.

Comment: Thanks, @Michele. Based on the solution you propose, would it be possible to make the user sees the "r" parameter on the URL all the time and no UTM tags, but behind the scenes we make that URL do have some UTM tags nobody sees (but Google Analytics tracks)? If so, how can we do this via GTM, supposing we already are able to capture the value of the "r" parameter? Thank you so much.

Comment: That's amazing, Michele, so much for this! So, I guess I'd need a condition that says "if query parameter r (which is saved on a variable) is NOT empty, then Field Name utm_campaign has a Value equals to the value of r". Google Analytics will force the UTM tags to be the ones I've specified and the user will not see any UTM tags on the URL but will keep seeing the r parameter. Is that correct? :) How would you set the condition for the variable that stores the value of parameter r, within GTM? Again, many many thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You don't need to store r value, just use it first time user lands on the page.

Comment: Until now I had a Google Analytics pageview tag configured to trigger on any page. Now I've created 2 duplicates of it (one that forces fields and looks like the one on your pic and that triggers when there's a parameter r on the URL, and another one that doesn't force anything -it's like the one by default- that triggers when there's NO parameter r on the URL). They should be mutually exclusive (only 1 should fire, never the 2 of them or none of them), so I've paused the initial tag to only leave the 2 new tags enabled. I guess I'll need to do the same with the rest of tags, right? Thanks! :)

Comment: Once the conditional routing I explained on my previous message is done, if the user moves to a different page than the landing one (e.g. /download), the set of UTM tags specified within the GTM conditions will still apply anywhere on the website, right? Even for the goals specified. And what if the "?r=" parameter is lost when the user goes to a different page within the same domain? If the UTM tags are kept, there's no need to design the same set of exclusive conditions for every tag and trigger, as the pageview executes at the very beginning and the UTM tags are propagated. Am I right? :)

Comment: Just send those values to Analytics the first time and they will be associated with the session ... if you think about it, even the UTMs you have them only on the first page and not on the following ones, however the pages you visit belong to the same session.

Comment: Amazing. I've tested the conditional and it works like a charm. Thanks for all the help, Michele!